# Sylius: require address in registration

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, sylius

**I want customers to fill in their address right at the registration, not at the checkout of an first order.**

I see, that `Sylius\Component\Core\Model\Customer` has attributes `$defaultAddress: AddressInterface` and `$addresses: Collection|AddressInterface[]`.

This is where I stucked. If there would be singular (`$address: AddressInterface`) I would know, I should extend form type and add there address field.

But how to require user to fill in exactly one address into this collection?

### I tried this:

My form type used for registration (where parent is `Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Form\Type\Customer\CustomerRegistrationType`):

`->add(
    'addresses',
    CollectionType::class,
    [
        'entry_type' => WholesaleCustomerAddressType::class
    ]
)`

Where WholesaleCustomerAddressType is child of `Sylius\Bundle\AddressingBundle\Form\Type\AddressType` and remove some fields (name, phone, etc.)

### How it works:

The address field at the registration page is not rendered (only empty div is). When I dump `form.adresses` I see it has no children.

It renders only this:

`<div data-form-type="collection" id="wholesale_customer_registration_addresses" class="form-control controls collection-widget" placeholder="Addresses"><div data-form-collection="list"></div></div>`

### How it should work:

The form should render fields for exactly one address. After click submit, the user should be registred, should has exactly one address and this address should be `$defaultAddress` also.

I see the problem is in the thing, that at the time of registration the collection of addresses is empty. How to add in Sylius a first record?

Comment: did you added `{{ form_row(form.addresses) }}` in specified twig template, where this form renders?

Comment: Actually I tried it, but I forgot to mention, that it rendered an empty div. When I dump form.addresses I can see it has no children. I updated my question to contain this info and rendered HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a little late but if someone else stumbles on your question, this is how I solved it...

As you pointed out yourself there is an attribute `$defaultAddress: AddressInterface`. Simply add this field to your custom form or in my case the form extension and assign the appropriate type. I used the `Sylius\Bundle\AddressingBundle\Form\Type\AddressType` and that's it.

My Form extension:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form\Extension;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Sylius\Bundle\AddressingBundle\Form\Type\AddressType;
use Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Form\Type\Customer\CustomerRegistrationType;

final class CustomerRegistrationTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        // Adding the defaultAddress as extra fields to the form        
        $builder->add('defaultAddress', AddressType::class, [
            'label' => 'sylius.form.customer.default_address',
        ]);

    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getExtendedTypes(): array
    {
        return [CustomerRegistrationType::class];
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add the extension as a service:

```
app.form.extension.type.customer_registration:
    class: App\Form\Extension\CustomerRegistrationTypeExtension
    tags:
        - { name: form.type_extension, extended_type: Sylius\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Form\Type\CustomerRegistrationType }
```

And don't forget to render the new field in tour template:

```
{{ form_row(form.defaultAddress) }}
```